# Does there exist an algorithm that decomposes a matrix into a minimal number of elementary matrices for $F_{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorial-optimization

If $i \neq j$, then let $C_{i,j} : F_{2}^{n} \to F_{2}^{n}$ be the *elementary* linear transformation defined by

$$C_{i,j}(x_{1},\dots,x_{i},\dots,x_{j},\dots,x_{n}) :=(x_{1},\dots,x_{i},\dots,x_{i}\oplus x_{j},\dots,x_{n})$$

which applies the [CNOT gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate) $(x,y)\mapsto(x,x \oplus y)$ to the $i$-th and $j$-th bits.

Does there exist an efficient algorithm that takes a non-singular linear transformation $L:F_{2}^{n} \to F_{2}^{n}$ and outputs a decomposition

$$L = C_{i_{r},j_{r}} \circ \cdots \circ C_{i_{1},j_{1}}$$

such that $r$ is minimized or nearly minimized?

I would like to find such an algorithm in order to optimize circuits composed almost exclusively of CNOT gates. A more general version of this question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615686/minimal-word-length-of-factorization-of-invertible-matrices-into-elementary-matr).

Comment: Yes. $\oplus$ is the standard notation for XOR which is addition modulo 2.

Comment: please define $CNOT$ gate.

Comment: I did define CNOT gate $(x,y)\mapsto(x,x\oplus y)$ in the question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate .

Comment: Does Gaussian elimination produce too large an $r$?

Comment: Rodrigo de Azevedo. I am to a large extent interested in the linear transformations where it is known that $r\ll n^{2}$ but where Gaussian elimination will take about $n^{2}$ steps. My uneducated guess is that the $r$ produced Gaussian elimination could be improved a little bit for random matrices though.

Comment: @JosephVanName, in doi:10.1016/j.aam.2006.08.008 there is an algorithm that improves the n^2 of Gaussian elimination to n^2/\log 2n, and this is asymtotically optimal according to doi:10.48550/ARXIV.1406.5826